# When touching on a tableviewCell, just part of the cell highlighted

Tags: swift, uitableview, highlight

I'm developing ViewController that shows a list of chatrooms.
And there are two problems.

1. though I had set height of tableviewcell, that cell wasn't showed entirely.

After I disabled the option 'clips to bounds', the cell is displayed with its correct height.

2. When I run that app on iPhone XR, it is highlighted normally.

However, when I run the app on other device(8, X), just part of cell is highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Disabling 'clips to bounds' will not affect you cell's height, it will only make the content that is outside of the cell's size visible (thus it would seem that the size has changed). That is why when selecting a cell will only highlight part of it, which is the cell's actual size. Long story short, the problem is that your cell size is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake.
I set height of cell in App storyboard and viewController too.
That confused the range of highlighted area.